# how to do about parallel arrays in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def menuListNo(m):
    '''(int) -> str
    From 1. Cake, menuListNo() function to 4. Cookie, the function 
    return string of Food name, Price in Dollar
    '''

    food = ['Cake', 'Pie', 'Ice cream', 'Cookie']
    price = [ 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

What is the function body in order to get both food name and price from the list to become the output by using number of food (1 - 4) as the input?

/ Can i use for-loop function? How?

```
for i, v in enumerate(menu):
```

The expected output:

```
 >>> menuListNo(2)
 'Pie 5 $'
 >>> menuListNo(4)
 'Cookie 3 $'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def menuListNo(m):
'''(int) -> str
From 1. Cake, menuListNo() function to 4. Cookie, the function 
return string of Food name, Price in Dollar
'''

    food = ['Cake', 'Pie', 'Ice cream', 'Cookie']
    price = [ 6, 5, 4, 3]

    print "{} {} $".format(food[m-1], price[m-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def menuListNo(m):
    '''(int) -> str
    From 1. Cake, menuListNo() function to 4. Cookie, the function 
    return string of Food name, Price in Dollar
    '''

    food = ['Cake', 'Pie', 'Ice cream', 'Cookie']
    price = [ 6, 5, 4, 3]
    joined =  zip(food,price)[m-1]
    # Convert to string
    return '%s %s $' %(joined[0], joined[1])
```

Comment: `zip`ing everything to acquire a single value is rather silly.

Answer (score 0):

If `food` and `price` may have different length itertools can help

```
import itertools
food = ['Cake', 'Pie', 'Ice cream', 'Cookie','Smoothie']
price = [ 6, 5, 4, 3]  
menu=['{item} {price}'.format(item=x[0],price=str(x[1])+'$' if x[1]>0 else 'not in menu')\
      for x in itertools.izip_longest(food,price,fillvalue=0)]
print menu
>>> ['Cake 6 $', 'Pie 5 $', 'Ice cream 4 $', 'Cookie 3 $', 'Smoothie not in menu']
```